# Tooltipster window not fit all content

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltipster

I use Tooltipster plugin for jquery.

When I use Bootstrap 3 button group as content of tooltip, tooltip width calculates incorrectly (several pixels) and appears second line.

Content generate programmatically:

```
$("<div/>",{class:"btn-group"}).append(
    $("<button/>",{type:"button",class:"btn btn-default"})
        .append( $("<span/>",{class:"glyphicon glyphicon-fast-backward"}) ),
    $("<button/>",{type:"button",class:"btn btn-default"})
        .append( $("<span/>",{class:"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"}) ),
    $("<button/>",{type:"button",class:"btn btn-default",id: "handler-content"}).text("1"),
    $("<button/>",{type:"button",class:"btn btn-default"})
        .append( $("<span/>",{class:"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"}) ),
    $("<button/>",{type:"button",class:"btn btn-default"})
        .append( $("<span/>",{class:"glyphicon glyphicon-fast-forward"}) )
);
```

Full situation: http://jsfiddle.net/YHXB5/1/

Comment: It's a bug in Tooltipster plugin https://github.com/iamceege/tooltipster/issues/146

Answer (score 1):

It's not specifically an issue *with* Tooltipster, the Bootstrap CSS sets the `box-sizing` attribute as follows:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

This messes up the content within your Tooltip. If you haven't seen the suggestions within the thread, a recommendation of using the following CSS "fix" pops up:

```
.tooltipster-base { box-sizing: content-box; }
```

This solves the issue, I've modified the JSFiddle to reflect this - if the fiddle doesn't work initially, move the slider around and it should "click" into place:

http://jsfiddle.net/YHXB5/2/

I hope this helps! :)